# Specific image asset not found - shopify

Tags: shopify

I want to use images from my shopify theme's assets folder in a custom .js script. (`product-customizer.js` added last in the following section)

In my template's liquid file i have:

```
<script> 
    var woodImageAsset = "{{ 'wood.jpg' | asset_url }}";
    var ajaxLoaderAsset =  "{{ 'ajax-loader.gif' | asset_url }}";
</script>
<script src="{{ 'uploadcare.full.min.js' | asset_url }}" defer="defer"></script>
<script src="{{ 'fabric.min.js' | asset_url }}" defer="defer"></script>
<script src="{{ 'product-customizer.js' | asset_url }}" defer="defer"></script>
```

I've been able to use every asset accept for `wood.jpg` just fine.

In `product-customizer.js` when i try to print the asset URLs from the CDN i get:

```
console.log(woodImageAsset);
//cdn2.shopify.com/s/files/1/0257/3995/2207/t/1/assets/wood.jpg?1012
console.log(ajaxLoaderAsset);
//cdn2.shopify.com/s/files/1/0257/3995/2207/t/1/assets/ajax-loader.gif?1012
```

Only `wood.jpg` is not found.

Note that `ajax-loader.gif` has already been included in the theme, while `wood.jpg` is aditionaly added in the theme's assets folder. Is there any special way to upload image assets to a shopify theme or am i missing something else?

Answer (score 2):

If you navigate to assets and examine the files, if you do not see wood.jpg then that means it is not available in that version of the theme. Simply grab a copy from another version of the theme where it is available, or upload it from your hard drive.

The other way to deal with images across all themes would be to upload the image as a file in the shop Settings -> Files section of your shop.

Comment: Thank you @David, i added the image through the web app like you suggested and the URL i got works fine now. Adding files manually through theme kit seems to be behaving strangely. Cheers